# Nothing happens when I run gulp

Tags: gulp

I have installed gulp using different ways like,

```
npm install gulp
npm install gulp -g
npm install gulp -g --save-dev
```

When I do gulp -v, it gives me the version but when I write gulp nothing happens. whats wrong?

Edit: Here is my gulp file,

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    // write something here
});

gulp.task('jshint', function(){
    gulp.src('js/script.js')
        .pipe(jshint)
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
})
```

Comment: try to run npm install and re-run gulp task. please, put your gulpfile here for more details 
github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/800

Comment: @Programmer21: I added my gulp file

Answer (score 1):

After debugging I found the solution. I had given a wrong name (gulp.js) to the gulp file. It should be gulpfile.js. I changed the name and it started working.